# Migrate gcp bucket dicom material to Ohif viewer

Tags: ohif

I am new to OHIF and I am looking forward using this Amazing looking tool .
Currently i have a working storescu(dcm4chee) server Retrieving dicom material from many modalities and all its material’s are stored into a GCP bucket (Google cloud bucket).
I am looking for a solution to View/Migrate them in OHIF Viewer.
Hope I made myself clear